# Rails 4 + Storing Email address in Cookie to Remember Me - Unable to store correct email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

Here, I am trying to store email address in cookie to autocomplete the email box as per last logged in user.

**Rails Controller Code :-**

```
cookies[:email] = { :value => user_email, :expires => 7.days.from_now }
```

For example - `admin@example.com` is the email address while inspecting the email address in cookie using debugger.

Its show

> admin%40example.com

By using JS I tried to retrieve the email address from cookie, now in input box it show

> admin%40example.com

Please suggest how to escape this symbol conversion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%40` is encoded form of `@`

I you are trying autocomplete the email address from jQuery, you can use this plain javascript function to decode it:

`var cookieEmail = decodeURIComponent('admin%40example.com')`

`$('#emailBox').val(cookieEmail)`

**(`#emailBox` is id assigned to the html element of your email input .)**

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks